# Gitlab yaml to azure pipelines yaml file

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment

I'm trying to convert but after reading some sources im not sure how I can convert this part of yaml code that works with gitlab CI to azure pipelines yaml:

```
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm run build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist
  only:
    - master

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - npm i -g netlify-cli
    - netlify deploy --site $NETLIFY_SITE_ID --auth $NETLIFY_AUTH_TOKEN --prod
  dependencies:
    - build
  only:
    - master
```

Especially I want to set the artifact path in the build stage and then somehow set that in the deploy stage.

Here how it looks now in my azure-pipelines yaml:

```
- script: |
    npm run build
  displayName: 'Build'

- script: |
    npm i -g netlify-cli
    netlify deploy --site $NETLIFY_SITE_ID --auth $NETLIFY_AUTH_TOKEN --prod
  displayName: 'Deploy'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See below sample:

```
variables:
  - name: netlify.site.id
    value: {value}
  - name: netlify.auth.token
    value: {token}

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'vs2017-win2016'

stages:
  - stage: Build
    jobs:
      - job: ARM
        steps:
        - script: npm -version
        - publish: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
          artifact: dist
  - stage: Deploy
    dependsOn: Build
    condition: succeeded()
    jobs:
      - job: APP
        steps:
        - bash: |
           npm i -g netlify-cli
           netlify deploy --site $(netlify.site.id) --auth $(netlify.auth.token) --prod
```

---

**Tip1:** If the value of `netlify.auth.token` and `netlify.site.id` is very private for you, and you do not want it public in YAML. You can store them in **variable group**. And then change the **Variables** part as:

```
variables:
  - group: {group name}
```

See this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#variables).

**Tip2:** For the stage dependency, you can use `dependsOn` keyword  in VSTS yaml to achieve the dependency. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#stage).

**Tip3:** In VSTS, you must specify `stages`, `jobs` and `steps` which used as the entry point for the server to compile the respective part.

> [A stage is a collection of related jobs.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#stage)
>
> [A job is a collection of steps to be run by an agent or on the
>   server.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#job)
>
> [Steps are a linear sequence of operations that make up a job.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#steps)

**Tip4:** To achieve publishing artifacts in VSTS with YAML, there has 2 different format. One is what I show for you above. **The publish keyword is a shortcut for the Publish Pipeline Artifact task.**

Another one format, see this [Publishing artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#publishing-artifacts)

Comment: Is there a way to keep folder between stages? For example in gitlab I could keep it this way: `cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/`

Comment: @AlexT If stage B is depending on stage A, then they can pass folder between stages by using artifacts. This is the most often used way, which also is mine and work fine. Did you need any other scenarios?

Comment: Yeah I presented the problem in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59085210/azure-pipelines-yaml-permission-denied

Comment: @AlexT, Have given you 2 method to try with. Do not hesitate to let me know if you has any puzzle in VSTS.